# Lightroom Preset/settings for dominant blue/orange-like look

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, color, presets

Do you know where can I get a Lightroom preset to be able to create an effect of two-color dominant orange-blue-like look? I mean something like this:

https://www.instagram.com/p/BXLzUWIFzjy/

or this:

https://www.instagram.com/p/BZCGynalpfu/

? They are a bit different, but they have something in common - two dominant complementary colors (blue and orange). The closest thing I've found is "Orange and Tilt" preset. It's similar to the second one, but the first looks more tricky - colors are darker and saturated and certainly, it's not tilt. I'm sure both of these images have been processed with a Lightroom preset, although I'm quite sure they have also been adjusted afterward. What I've been trying was to use the Camera Calibration as well as HSL, but I've never been able to reproduce such look. Can someone recognize the preset and tell me its name?

Comment: There's nothing magic about a LR preset. You can move the controls and do the same thing yourself (and maybe learn a lot about color in the process). But I suspect these images are more than just color adjustments. They're possibly composites (parts of two or more images combined).

Comment: Why not contact the person who posted these images ?  They would know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use the Lightroom split toning tool. Hold down the alt key to see the area of effect.
https://photographylife.com/how-to-split-tone-photos-in-lightroom

Comment: This is the correct answer. The method is called "Split Toning" and involves changing the hue of the highlights and the shadows. Once you get the effect you want you can then save that as a preset.